# Plugins or editors for Haskell source code navigation

Tags: haskell, vim, emacs, editor

I'm looking for Vim/Emacs plugins or other editors for handily going through Haskell source code with two major built-in features:

- code fold/unfold per function/type/typeclass;
- jump to function/type/typeclass definition in the dependent module.

(Haskell website and Hoogle are nice but not what I really pursue.)

Comment: You could use tagbar with hasktags suport: https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar/wiki#haskell

Answer (score 1):

In vim, you can `:set foldmethod=indent` to approximate the first. Use [`hasktags`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hasktags) together with vim's builtin tags support for the second (see especially `Ctrl-]`, `Ctrl-T`, and in larger projects, `:tnext` and `:tprevious`).

Answer (score 1):

See IntelliJ plugin for Haskell:
https://github.com/rikvdkleij/intellij-haskell

Available in Jetbrains plugins repo